# n-th iteration of T is contraction mapping, must m-th iteration (m>n) of T be a contraction mapping?

Tags: functional-analysis, contraction-mapping

$T$ is a self-map on a metric space $M$. $M$ is not necessarily complete.

$T$ itself is not a contraction mapping, but $n$-th iteration of $T$ is a contraction mapping.

Must $T^m$ ($m>n$) be a contraction mapping as well?

The intuition is no. But I cannot find a nice counterexample.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Is $T$ supposed to be continuous? Or just any point-set-map?

Comment: @Cosine. No assumption on $T$ is made. $T^n$, of course, has to be continuous since it is a contraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to come up with an example of linear contraction on the euclidean plane. Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2^{-1/2} & (2N)^{-1} \\
N & -2^{-1/2}\end{pmatrix}$$ Then
$A^2=I.$ For $T=2^{-1}A$ the mapping $T^2=4^{-1}I$ is a contraction on $\mathbb{R}^2.$  However $T^3=8^{-1}A$ is not a contraction for $N>8$ as $$d(T^3e_1,0)=8^{-1}d(Ae_1,0)>8^{-1}N>1=d(e_1,0)$$ where $e_1,e_2$ denote the elements of the standard basis.
Thus $T$ is not a contraction either.

Comment: Thanks. This example looks good! It also serves as a good example that all eigenvalue stictly less than 1 is not sufficient for the linear transformation to be a contraction.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. It is possible to come up with example so that $T^{2n-1}$ is not a contraction for any $n$ while $T^{2n}$ is a contraction for all $n.$. However the space is not complete.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider $M = \{0, 2,3,6,8\}$ (equipped with the Euclidean distance) and the map $T$ defined via
$$
T(0) = T(2) = 0, \quad T(3) = 2, \quad T(6) = 3, \quad T(8) = 6.
$$
Then, it can be checked that
$$
d(T(6),T(8)) = d(3,6) = 3 > 2 = d(6,8)
$$
and
$$
d(T^3(6), T^3(8)) = d(0,2) = 2 = d(6, 8),$$
i.e., $T$ and $T^3$ are not contractive.
However, by looking at
$$
T^2(0) = T^2(2) = T^2(3) = 0, \quad T^2(6) = 2, \quad T^2(8) = 3$$
we see that $T^2$ is a contraction.

Comment: That works. Thank you!

Comment: @WilliamWang If the answer was useful, I suggest that you mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos. I tried to vote up this answer. But the community doesn't allow me to do so since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @WilliamWang My suggestion was for you to *accept* the answer. I made no mention about upvoting it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos How to accept an anwser? I am quite new to this community...

Comment: @WilliamWang Just click the ✓ sign, which is located below the downvote arrow.